# C program not responding after scanf statement

Tags: c

My code compiles and also it runs. But after taking input it does not execute the next statement of the program.

It takes all input elements of the array then it does not do anything. I think there is problem after second `scanf` statement which is inside the `for` loop.

I am not sure that the code is correct but after compiling and running, I am expecting that it should give the final output even if it is not as expected (or incorrect).

I am using `Code::Blocks(16.01)` as IDE.
My operating system is Windows 8.1(64-bit).

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quick(int *, int, int);

int main() {
    int n, i, pivot, j, k, l, u;

    printf("Give size\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n];
    printf("Enter the list\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    quick(a, 1, n - 1);
    printf("\nSorted numbers are\n");
    for (i = 1; i <=n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quick(int a[], int l, int u) {
    int pivot, j, temp, i;
    pivot = a[l];
    i = l;
    j = u;

    while (i <= j) {
        if (a[i] > pivot && a[j] < pivot) {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        } 
        else if (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        else if (a[j] > pivot)
            j--;
    }
    quick(a, l, j - 1);
    quick(a, j + 1, u);
}
```

[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02q5r.png)

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` writing to address which you do not own.

Comment: The index of the first element of an array is 0.

Comment: @babon I did not get it. Are you saying that something is wrong in deceleration of the array?

Comment: 1) `for(i=1;i<=n;i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);` --> `for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);` because C is 0 origin.

Comment: @nikunj_r Array indexes in C start from 0 and can go up to one less than the size of the array. You should loop from `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: `else if(a[i] < pivot) i++;` : first time `a[i] == pivot` So This loop is an infinite loop and does not end. Also your logic does not basically consider that the same value exists.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But what if we consider that all the elements of the array are distinct. And sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Even if everything is separate, you need a case of equal because you choose `pivot` from among them. In general there is no guarantee that all of the sequences are distinct. If all is the same as an example(`{5,5,5,5,5}`), none of `if` in your logic will execute the body.

Comment: `int a[n];` is wrong. size of array must be const if declared as auto

Comment: @duong_dajgja It is called VLA and can be used after C99.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY then it's not standard defined?

Comment: @duong_dajgja **C99** is standard. (Option in C11)

Comment: @duong_dajgja you have missed last 20 years. Some kind of hibernation?

Answer (score 1):

As other people pointed out in comments, you're doing some mistakes:

1. You've declared your array as `int a[n]`; and array indexing starts from 0, then why are you passing the array like it's indexing starts from 1 ? You need to change those for loops to : `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` and you quicksort call like this: `quick(a,0,n-1);`.
2. You quicksort logic seems flawed. You choose `a[l]` as your pivot but you include that in your partitioning logic. You're also not checking for the base condition of your recursion, i.e `l < u`.
3. After partiioning the array you're supposed to swap the pivot with the mid element of your partition (i.e last element of first half or the first element of second half, depending upon your choice). I changed your quicksort function like [this](https://gist.github.com/rohanKanojia/d7c2327742480cd7367bc133e9da823f). And i was able to see the desired output.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your first point is correct, but not the others, if the pivot is a scalar value, its value can be copied to a local variable `pivot` and you can include it in the partitioning logic and there is no need to swap it back in at the end.  Hoare's original algorithm does just that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: @chqrlie: ah, Nice catch. I didn't know about this. Thanks for your nitpick ;) . Will give it  a read for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your for loop,begin from 0 since C is 0 origin.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

C function parameters are always "pass-by-value", which means that the function scanf only sees a copy of the current value of whatever you specify as the argument expression.

Array name returns the pointer of the first element of a array (memory location where array is stored), and name of the scalar variable returns the value of the scalar, so you need to use & operator to get the memory location of scalar in which you need to write the value.

**And kindly check your Quick sort logic and calling**

Comment: @nikunj_r please check your quick sort logic.

Comment: I checked that. Thanks for your help :-) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of your program with some small modifications:

1) The first element is chosen as pivot

2) Check stop condition of the recursive function, that is `if (lo >= hi) { return; }`

3) Swap the pivot element with element at index `i-1` after the `while` loop

4) Include equality in `else if (a[i] <= pivot)` and `else if (a[j] >= pivot)` to prevent infinitive loop when an element has the same value as pivot, for example `1 1 3 5`

```
#include <stdio.h>


void quick(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if (lo >= hi)
    {
        return;
    }

    int pivot, j, temp, i;
    pivot = a[lo];
    i = lo + 1;
    j = hi;

    while (i <= j)
    {
        if (a[i] > pivot && a[j] < pivot)
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if (a[i] <= pivot)
            i++;
        else if (a[j] >= pivot)
            j--;
    }

    int l = i - 1;
    temp = a[l];
    a[l] = a[lo];
    a[lo] = temp;

    quick(a, lo, l-1);
    quick(a, l+1, hi);
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_NUM = 100;
    int arr[MAX_NUM];

    int n = 0;
    printf("How many numbers? n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n < 1 || n > 100)
    {
        printf("Invalid input. Nothing to do\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Sorting...\n");
    quick(arr, 0, n-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: In the stop condition of recursive function when i use if(lo>hi){ return; } then also it runs correctly. I want to know whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you can even modify as per your choice:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = (low - 1); 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++; // increment index of smaller element
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}
/*
arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
low --> Starting index,
high --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int arr[100], n,i;
    printf("Enter the size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter your Array List:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    quickSort(arr, 0, n-1);
    printf("Sorted array: ");
    printArray(arr, n);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in your code:

- you do not check the return values of `scanf()`.
- arrays are `0` based in C. The loop logic should read

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- similarly, if the bounds are included in the function `quick`, which is not the classic way to do things in C, the function call should read:

  ```
  quick(a, 0, n - 1);
  ```
- avoid naming a variable `l`, it look confusingly similar to `1`.
- The QuickSort algorithm in function `quick` seems incorrect. Here is an extensive reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quick(int *, int, int);

int main(void) {
    int n, i;

    printf("Give size\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    int a[n];
    printf("Enter the list\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    quick(a, 0, n - 1);
    printf("\nSorted numbers are\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quick(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
        int pivot = a[lo];
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi + 1;
        int temp;

        for (;;) {
            while (a[++i] < pivot)
                continue;
            while (a[--j] > pivot)
                continue;
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        quick(a, lo, j);
        quick(a, j + 1, hi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to check return value of `scanf()`? Because generally the code runs correctly without it.

Comment: @nikunj_r:  The code run correctly as long as the input is correct. Testing the return value is the only way to detect incorrect input, such as a letter when expecting a number.  Invalid input will cause the program to have undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay. And your suggestion about avoiding the naming of variable like `l` was helpful. :-) .